# Fast tensor-dot on sparse arrays with GPU in any programming language?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, cupy

I'm now working on two multi-dimensional arrays `arr` and `cost`. `arr` is dense with size `(width, height, m, n)` and `cost` is sparse with size `(width, height, width, height)`.

Values: `width` and `height` are around `5000`, `m` is less than `100`, and `n` is less than `10`. The sparse `cost` is strictly block-sparse. For `cost[i,j,:,:]`, there are only a certain `k*k` block, where `k` is less than `50`.

Now I want this:

```
result = np.tensordot(cost, arr, axes=[[2,3],[0,1]])
```

The size of `result` is then `(width, height, m, n)` (the same as `arr`). However the `cost` array is too large if defined as a dense array.

So, the question is: How to do a fast tensor-dot (better with GPU) on sparse arrays?

Possible solutions are ideas in any programming language are OK, including but not limited to Python, C++, Julia, etc.

---

I've tried:

CPU versions (multithreaded): C++ (simply with `std::vector`), `numpy`/`scipy`, Julia

GPU versions: `cupy`, `CUDA.jl`

The C++ version works well with some simple for-loops on `std::vector`s, but it is not fast enough.

With `cupy` and `CUDA.jl`, they all work very fast on small tests with `width` and `height` set to small values and define both `cost` and `arr` are dense. But I don't know how to modify it to a sparse version.

Comment: `np.tensordot` uses `reshape` and transpose` to  convert the 4d task into a 2d `dot`, and then back.  `sparse` packages generally work with 2d arrays, and are best when both arrays (and the desired result) are sparse.  Extensions to higher dimensions are not as common or developed.  My guess is your c++ approach will be best, but without code (and proper tags) you won't get much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this finally via `cupy` with some reshapings.

I've implemented the Julia version tensor-dot with reshaping but I didn't realize this is the key to solving this 2d-sparse-matrix problem. Thanks for @hpaulj who reminded me of this.

The minimal example is:

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from cupyx.scipy import sparse as sparse_gpu
from scipy import sparse as sparse_cpu

# sparse_cost2d_cpu = get_cost_cpu(...)
data = cp.asarray(sparse_cost2d_cpu.data,dtype=DTYPE_CP)
indices = cp.asarray(sparse_cost2d_cpu.indices)
indptr = cp.asarray(sparse_cost2d_cpu.indptr)
sparse_cost2d_gpu = sparse_gpu.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(width*height,width*height),dtype=DTYPE_CP)

arr4d_cpu = np.random.random((width, height, nvar, nvalue)).astype(DTYPE_NP)
arr2d_cpu = arr.reshape((width*height,nvar*nvalue))
arr2d_gpu = cp.asarray(arr2d_cpu)

for i in range(100):
    new_arr2d_gpu = sparse_cost2d_gpu.dot(arr2d_gpu)
    arr2d_gpu = new_arr2d_gpu*_lambda + arr2d_gpu*(1-_lambda)
    arr4d_gpu = arr2d_gpu.reshape((width,height,nvar,nvalue))
    # Some other computation with arr4d_gpu
    arr2d_gpu = arr4d_gpu.reshape((width*height,nvar*nvalue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tensordot can be evaluated with other numpy tools, and expressed as a `dot` of 2d arrays.

For illustration purposes I won't try to push sizes, or make anything sparse.  The sparseness of `cost` is not all that clear anyways.

Smallish dimensions, with reproducible values:

```
In [852]: width, height, m, n = 10,10,5,4    
In [853]: arr = np.arange(width*height*m*n).reshape(width,height,m,n)    
In [854]: cost = np.arange(10**4).reshape(10,10,10,10)
```

Your tensordot

```
In [856]: res = np.tensordot(cost,arr,((2,3),(0,1)))    
In [857]: res.shape
Out[857]: (10, 10, 5, 4)
```

The equivalent using `einsum`:

```
In [859]: res1=np.einsum('ijkl,klmn->ijmn',cost,arr)    
In [860]: res1.shape
Out[860]: (10, 10, 5, 4)

In [861]: np.allclose(res,res1)
Out[861]: True
```

Using `matmul/dot` with 2d arrays:

```
In [863]: res2=cost.reshape(10*10,10*10)@arr.reshape(10*10,-1)
In [864]: res2.shape
Out[864]: (100, 20)

In [865]: np.allclose(res, res2.reshape(res.shape))
Out[865]: True
```

`tensordot` is doing the same reshaping.